# Failed building twisted[tls] on Windows?

Tags: python-3.x, twisted, django-channels

I've tried to install `channels 2.4.0` into a `python 3.8.1` venv on Windows 10. I'm using `django 2.2.9`. The installation fails during build of `twisted[tls]` wheels:

```
Collecting twisted[tls]>=18.7
  Using cached Twisted-19.10.0.tar.bz2 (3.1 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=2.7 in c:\users\florian\.virtualenvs\mvp_industrial-mzsq8pv8\lib\site-packages (from autobahn>=0.18->daphne~=2.3->channels) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: txaio>=20.1.1 in c:\users\florian\.virtualenvs\mvp_industrial-mzsq8pv8\lib\site-packages (from autobahn>=0.18->daphne~=2.3->channels) (20.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: zope.interface>=4.4.2 in c:\users\florian\.virtualenvs\mvp_industrial-mzsq8pv8\lib\site-packages (from twisted[tls]>=18.7->daphne~=2.3->channels) (4.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: constantly>=15.1 in c:\users\florian\.virtualenvs\mvp_industrial-mzsq8pv8\lib\site-packages (from twisted[tls]>=18.7->daphne~=2.3->channels) (15.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: incremental>=16.10.1 in c:\users\florian\.virtualenvs\mvp_industrial-mzsq8pv8\lib\site-packages (from twisted[tls]>=18.7->daphne~=2.3->channels) (17.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Automat>=0.3.0 in c:\users\florian\.virtualenvs\mvp_industrial-mzsq8pv8\lib\site-packages (from twisted[tls]>=18.7->daphne~=2.3->channels) (0.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: hyperlink>=17.1.1 in c:\users\florian\.virtualenvs\mvp_industrial-mzsq8pv8\lib\site-packages (from twisted[tls]>=18.7->daphne~=2.3->channels) (19.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyHamcrest>=1.9.0 in c:\users\florian\.virtualenvs\mvp_industrial-mzsq8pv8\lib\site-packages (from twisted[tls]>=18.7->daphne~=2.3->channels) (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.4.0 in c:\users\florian\.virtualenvs\mvp_industrial-mzsq8pv8\lib\site-packages (from twisted[tls]>=18.7->daphne~=2.3->channels) (19.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyopenssl>=16.0.0 in c:\users\florian\.virtualenvs\mvp_industrial-mzsq8pv8\lib\site-packages (from twisted[tls]>=18.7->daphne~=2.3->channels) (19.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: service_identity>=18.1.0 in c:\users\florian\.virtualenvs\mvp_industrial-mzsq8pv8\lib\site-packages (from twisted[tls]>=18.7->daphne~=2.3->channels) (18.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna!=2.3,>=0.6 in c:\users\florian\.virtualenvs\mvp_industrial-mzsq8pv8\lib\site-packages (from twisted[tls]>=18.7->daphne~=2.3->channels) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8 in c:\users\florian\.virtualenvs\mvp_industrial-mzsq8pv8\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=2.7->autobahn>=0.18->daphne~=2.3->channels) (1.13.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.4.1 in c:\users\florian\.virtualenvs\mvp_industrial-mzsq8pv8\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=2.7->autobahn>=0.18->daphne~=2.3->channels) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\florian\.virtualenvs\mvp_industrial-mzsq8pv8\lib\site-packages (from zope.interface>=4.4.2->twisted[tls]>=18.7->daphne~=2.3->channels) (45.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules in c:\users\florian\.virtualenvs\mvp_industrial-mzsq8pv8\lib\site-packages (from service_identity>=18.1.0->twisted[tls]>=18.7->daphne~=2.3->channels) (0.2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1 in c:\users\florian\.virtualenvs\mvp_industrial-mzsq8pv8\lib\site-packages (from service_identity>=18.1.0->twisted[tls]>=18.7->daphne~=2.3->channels) (0.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\florian\.virtualenvs\mvp_industrial-mzsq8pv8\lib\site-packages (from cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8->cryptography>=2.7->autobahn>=0.18->daphne~=2.3->channels) (2.19)
Building wheels for collected packages: twisted
  Building wheel for twisted (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\florian\.virtualenvs\mvp_industrial-mzsq8pv8\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Florian\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4pveivx4\\twisted\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Floria
n\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4pveivx4\\twisted\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Florian\Ap
pData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-te0p20uj'
       cwd: C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4pveivx4\twisted\
[...]
  copying src\twisted\words\xish\xpathparser.g -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\twisted\words\xish
  warning: BuildPy3: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

  running build_ext
  building 'twisted.test.raiser' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for twisted
  Running setup.py clean for twisted
Failed to build twisted
```

To me it's not clear what components (which compiler, etc. like e.g. `C++-Clang-cl für v142-Buildtools (x64/x86)`, `C++ v14.20-ATL für v142-Buildtools (x86 und x64)`, etc.) to choose from when installing the current MS Visual C++ 2019. How can I make the installation succeed?

Comment: How are you trying to install it?

Comment: I tried to install channels into the venv with `pipenv install channels==2.4.0`. twisted was implicit downstream dependency.

Comment: I suppose the issue is that Twisted does not distribute Python 3.8 binaries for Windows (I think because no release of Twisted officially supports Python 3.8 yet).  If you can switch to Python 3.7 you won't have to compile anything.  Otherwise, you'll have to figure out how to get the right C compiler and this question generalizes to "How do I build extensions for Python 3.8 on Windows?"

Comment: Based on https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#compiling-python-on-windows I guess you need "Microsoft Visual Studio 2015".

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone I used `Twisted-19.10.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl` with python 3.8.1 successfully. However due to another issue I had to swtich to python 3.7 anyway. I used the pre-built wheel as well. Did not try to build on my own right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current workaround is to download a pre-built `twisted 19.10.0` from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted), put it into a deps folder and install it with pipenv install `deps\Twisted-19.10.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl` prior to installing `channels 2.4.0`. However it seems like the website provides latest package versions only. It would be nice to beeing able to reproduce specific older versions as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue,Its probably because twisted is yet not configurable with python 3.8(as pointed out by Jean).
I solved it by degading my Python version to 3.7 instead of 3.8 in conda:

```
conda install python==3.7
```